# Change java.util log levels in tomcat (or tomEE or openEJB)

Tags: tomcat, logging, apache-tomee, openejb

I have the following Logger defined in servlet.

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestServlet.class.getName());
```

Changed logger levels in logging.properties, But

```
LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "hello");
```

doesn't print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has integrity issues with tomcat. But the following steps helped.

- Open Server configuration by double clicking the server (in servers
  Tab)
- Click Open lauch configuration
- In Arguments tab add the following to the JVM arguments

`-Djava.util.logging.config.file="{your tomcat folder}\conf\logging.properties"

 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`

To change the logging levels,

Through configuration:

Edit logging.properties to add logging levels

`com.level = FINE`

Or through code:

`static {
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINE);
}`